# Clear text of UITextField in UITableView cell on button press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a table view with two rows, each with a text field. One text field is for username and the other for password. When I click on a button, I want to clear both fields and replace the contents with the intial placeholders.
I tried `[mytableview reloadData];`. That just reloads the table view; the text fields are not cleared. The placeholders are appearing over the text entered while editing the text field, and the next time I try to edit the text field, the text is drawn over the first text.

Comment: I know it's your decision but using a tableview for two cells namely textfields looks like overkill by means of code maintenance.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some problems with your table cell re-use code. If the placeholders are OVER the text you are entering, then there are some serious drawing issues - or multiple text fields being added on top of each other.

Comment: @ Michael Petrov..Thank u for ur response....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your button click:-
do `yourtextfieldname.text=@"";`

or if you have made a text field in table view methods so in that condition on your button click do `[tableView reloadData]` and at cellForRowAtIndexPath write yourtextfieldname.text=@"";
and set placeholder also.

Comment: @Gypsa how can i get textfieldName object if my textfield is custom class object i.e. customcell.textField